# How to access localhost/drupal from the internet?

Tags: php, apache, drupal-7, wamp, wampserver

I have created a simple website whose url is localhost/drupal. But I couldn't access it from the internet. (i,e from another laptop connected to my home router). I have all settings in the httpd.conf file under Apache set correctly as instructed. i,e "Require all granted" is set. I use Apache 2.4.9 and Latest wamp. I.I use drupal 7.14.

I try to access the url by "internalIPaddress/drupal" i,e 192.168.2.10/drupal. also tried typing just 192.168.2.17 from the other laptop on my home network.nothing seems to workout.!! Pls assist.!!

How to access the site from outside the network.

Comment: you must edit with more info about how you connect to internet

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable local network users access my WAMP sites hosted on a windows8 laptop connected to a router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-access-my-wamp-sites-hosted-on-a-windows8-lapt)

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download). It's free.

Then, from your terminal (assuming your drupal site runs on port `http://localhost:8888/`).

```
$ ngrok 8888
```

ngrok will assign you a subdomain for you. Open the url, and you are good to go.

You can also sign up for free to be able to choose a name for your subdomain.

```
$ ngrok -subdomain=mysubdomain 8888 # ngrok will assign you http://mysubdomain.ngrok.com/
```

### Update

As of ngrok 2, you need to type `http PORT_NUMBER`

```
$ ngrok http 8888
```

OR

```
$ ngrok http -subdomain=mysubdomain 8888
```

Comment: If you're serving multiple sites from the same computer you might need to put a new entry in your vhosts.conf or similar file pointing your ngrok domain to the correct system path, like:

    <VirtualHost *:8083>  
      ServerName randstring.ngrok.io  
      DocumentRoot "/path/to/site/drupal"  
    ...

Answer (score 0):

first you have to know your ip you can do that you can follow this steps:

> Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type
>   adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View
>   network connections. Select an active network connection, and then, in
>   the toolbar, click View status of this connection. (You might need to
>   click the chevron Picture of the chevron icon to find this command.)
>
> Click Details.
>
> Your computer's IP address appears in the Value column, next to IPv4
>   Address.

Yo can read more in:

> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-computers-ip-address#1TC=windows-7

Then you can enter to Drupal from another pc in your network with:

```
http://your_ip_adress/drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

Open WAMP menu (the icon) and choose *Put Online*, this will accept external connections around your local network. If you've public address, this will allow to publish your website for the internet, however `192.168.*.*` is subset of [private addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). But it's enough for access from the other laptop on my home network.

See: [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24005828/55075) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

check your laptop IPv4 Address

```bash
ipconfig
```

> for example IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6

then try to run your drupal project with steps below

```bash
cd web
```

```bash
php -S 0.0.0.0:8888 .ht.router.php
```

then you can open http://192.168.1.6:8888 in your other laptop