# Create Server with Wamp

Tags: php, networking, web, wamp, broadcast

I am using a network PC, and I installed WampServer in my local machine. Can I use this WampServer for a local site to broadcast in local network?

I have created a site http://testsite/ which is working only in my system. Now I want to use the same site in other PC, which is in same LAN network? I did this with IIS, but I have no idea about the WAMP. Is this possible?

I tried to update `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. But it's working locally, not in network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)

Answer (score -1):

Find out These lines and replace with the:

```
ServerName localhost:80
HostnameLookups Off
```

Replace with

```
ServerName testsite:80
HostnameLookups on
```

And if you want to share with local System just share you IP in the network.

Comment: That is not going to allow access from other PC's on the LAN