# How to access virtual host from another machine in lan?

Tags: apache, lan, vhosts

I've installed wamp 2.5 on Windows 7. I created a virtual host and I can access normally on my machine. But every other machine in LAN keeps getting "Forbidden" error. I have these settings on my httpd-vhosts.conf .

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#virtualHost that I want to make available in LAN

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/medenuncia/public"
ServerName medenuncia.local
<Directory  "c:/wamp/www/medenuncia/public">
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've already searched similar questions but none worked for me. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: How could you access the virtual host from the other computer? do you use, for example, `192.168.1.20` -the IP of computer that hosts the virtual host? OR you just write in address bar of the second computer's browser `medenunica.local`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)