# Wamp server httpd.conf syntax error

Tags: wampserver, httpd.conf

I am trying to make webpage accessible outside network. I found process to do it.

It says find section " Order Deny,Allow  Deny from all"and make changes. problem is:

1. I don't see that section at all. I tried to add suggested sentences according to previous and next statements. but it says syntax error. so not able to restart services. i did put tab space between two lines. what is right way to add statements?
2. Also, the content in this file are straight in line. so not easy to read. can i change, so that it will be readable?

I am also getting syntax error in phpmyadmin.conf . the problem is in last line. 
code looks like this: 
    Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"
    # to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
    # replace the lines
    #
    # Require local
    #
    # by
    #
    # Require all granted
    #

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
   Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    order Allow,Deny    Allow from all  Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1</IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have to assume you are using WAMPServer2.4 or WAMPServer2.5

I hope 2.5 so start by reading the [WAMPServer 2.5 release notes and corrections](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685)

Before that download a decent editor, the document suggests Notepad++ as its good and free. That will see the files properly that mistakenly got release with Unix line endings.

For allowing external access have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites/24011132#24011132) The syntax used by Apache 2.4.x has changed from the `Allow` to `Require`

Comment: Probably best to ask another question, as its supposed to be one question per question. I will look out for it.