# WAMP server is not accessible by local network

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I was trying to get my WAMP server up and running, but I can'
t access my website from other computers.

My local IP is `192.168.0.6` and the port that's being used by Apache is `8080`.
So when I try accessing it from another computer by using `192.168.0.6:8080`, it can not find my server.

The server runs fine and the ports are not being used by any other program, just other computers cannot access the server. I even tried pressing the `Put Online` button but even that does not work.

The server is running Wampserver32 3.0.6 on Windows 8.1 x86.

Comment: These other computers are on your local network right?

Comment: Yes, the other computers are on the **same** local network.

Comment: did you try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites ?

Comment: OK, I tried that, and changed `Require local` to `Require all granted` and added another line that has `Require ip 192.168.0` in httpd-vhosts.conf. I restarted both servers and it still doesn't work.