# Wamp, Connect Local Network User

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

Once Our Wamp Server is Running successfully and also we can able to make 
   access to my local network users in wamp. In-between that, Unfortunately anyone 
   Install wamp to their system, How can we solve the problem? I can't able to 
   Reconnect to All my localhost users.

Thanks for Advance.

Answer (score -1):

After starting WAMP, Icon will be display in green in Windows Tray, click right button on it. Then click on Make Online - that's it.

Then you can access by IP address of that system from LAN.

Comment: Still Now I can't able to connect. :(

Comment: what are you getting in browser?

Comment: This site can’t be reached
192.168.11.119 took too long to respond.

Comment: what is default port number of apache?

Comment: My Port Number is Apache 80

Comment: Check this Answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites