# Setting up localhost between Xubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7

Tags: php, ubuntu, windows-7, localhost, apache2

I have everything configured and working great within my Xubuntu 16.04 machine, including localhost (I am using LAMP stack, apache2, php7.0).

I am struggling to configure the localhost on my Windows 7 machine so that I can view my work on my google chrome browser in the Windows environment. I wasn't able to find any tutorials on how to set this up. Do I need to configure this within the apache2.conf within the virtual machine or? Thanks for any help in advance.

I have tried localhost localhost:8080 and localhost:8081

Comment: You said it yourself, you made your localhost -> Hosting on your computer only. You'd need to redirect your router connection towards your main server.

But that's just a bit more complicated. You could use Bitbucket service to sync your work on the cloud (repository system) and set up individual local servers on n machines.

Comment: Regular old apache is normally port 80, so just localhost should do it, on the same machine. On a different machine on the network, you'll need the ipaddress, and might have to contend with Windows Firewall.

Comment: @Adrián do I need to place the windows IP address somewhere within the apache2.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computers are on the same network use the command "arp -a" on your windows machine to view all of the ip addresses on your network. Replace the localhost on your windows system with that of the one on the Xubuntu machine.

(Don't forget to add the port for the apache server!)

**Localhost:8080 -> 192.186.0.30:8080**

Comment: thanks for your response! I was able to track down the IP of both the windows machine and ubuntu machine but I am having trouble with where I edit that change on windows and also how to add the port in the apache server. I can get into the port.conf but I am unsure where/how to place the windows IP

Comment: @willking What is your end goal, are you just hoping to view content server by the Xubuntu machine?

Comment: currently, if I make changes to my website within ubuntu, I can see those changes through the localhost within that machine without pushing anything. I would also like to also see those same changes through my browser on my windows machine.

Comment: The best way to do it is to click on the wamp icon and enable "Put Online"

You could also use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24011132/7925972)

@willking