# How to use localhost site from my android phone?

Tags: android, wamp, wampserver

I am building a website and I am using wampserver 3.0.6 to build it in localhost.

I was able to access wampserver homepage from Android phone Chrome browser by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011132 answer for WAMPServer 3 and above. But how can I access my localhost website from wampserver homepage? I typed my laptop's ipv4 address into my android phone chrome browser and was able to get to wampserver homepage, but how to go to localhost site?

Comment: have you setup your content in the webserver? Can you access it from the Desktop?

Comment: You put the full URL to the page? Or you replace the index.php file

Comment: Yes..i am using localhost/mysite for visiting site.

Comment: `But how can I access my localhost website from wampserver homepage?` ??? A page that should access a website? Never heard of that. And every device is its own localhost so about which device/server are you talking? And where is your wamp server running? It looks like you have two servers. Pretty unclear setup.

Comment: I will make it clear..i run wamp server on a laptop and i need to access localhost site hosted on laptop,from my phone.

Comment: Do not call that that a localhost site if all that you want is calling a php script on your laptop. Now do you?

Comment: Show the url you use to call the wampserver from your Android device. Also show the url you use to call the php script.

Comment: Is your website php or html?

Comment: The website is both php and html

Comment: Url used for calling from laptop browser is http://localhost/mysite

Comment: You did not show one url. And i asked you even two. Those which you use from your Android device. Be serious! Someone tries to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

My wamp server www root:

c:\wamp64\www

My index.php is here:

c:\wamp64\www\test\index.php

From browser goto:

http://'ip to wamp server'/test/index.php

Hope it helps.