# Not getting response from URL in gson +volley+recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

i am making FriendManagementApp. I want to fetch response from the local host.I am using gson,volley,recyclerview but I am not getting response.

```
private void requestJsonObject() throws AuthFailureError 
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://192.168.1.50:8080/*************/";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           try{
           // Log.d(TAG, "Response " + response);
            GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson mGson = builder.create();
            List<FriendsData> posts = new ArrayList<FriendsData>();
            posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, FriendsData[].class));
            Log.i("MainActivity", posts.size() + " posts loaded.");
            for (FriendsData data : posts) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", data.getId() + ": " + data.getFirstname() + ": " + data.getLastname() + ":" + data.getContact());
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts);
                //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                // recyclerView.getAdapter().addAll(posts);
                // recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChaged();
                System.out.println(data.getId());

            }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            System.out.print(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are you using using emulator or testing it on device?

Comment: I have tried on both.

Comment: is there any Error response comes or not ???

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator to connect to local machine use `10.0.2.2` IP address instead of `192.168.1.50`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-android-emulator) link

Comment: Thankyou for your help but i have already used this and it was not working therefore i have used my IP address and still it is not working

Comment: Try disabling firewall or antivirus just for debugging purpose.

Comment: I am using LINUX

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: As I said above try disabling firewall. Check this link: https://superuser.com/questions/794104/how-to-permanently-disable-firewall-in-red-hat-linux

Answer (score 0):

*I am assume that you installed LAMP server on your local machine.*

- You should open your local host's 8080 port for inbound rules.
- Try to connect that url with your local browser.
- If it is ok, put your LAMP server online. [See Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011132/4133449)