# Accessing Wamp 3.1.0 from other devices

Tags: apache, wamp, local

I have Wamp Server 3.1.0 installed on my Windows computer.

I am trying to access my sites from other devices, connected are connected on the same network.

I have searched online. And I have followed tutorials, but nothing matches what I need. The closest I got was: [How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)

My *httpd-vhosts.conf* looks like this:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/projects/forum/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/projects/forum/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/projects/test/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/projects/test/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My expectation at this point is I can go onto another device and access my Wamp Server 3.1.0 and my individual projects.

Unfortunately I'm hit with an Error 500 saying:

```
Forbiddon

You do not have permission to access / on this server.
_______________________________________________________________
Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9 Server at 192.168.1.21 Port 80
```

I have double checked my ipconfig and IPv4 Address matches the IP in the Error 500 code: 192.168.1.21

I did notice that the Apache version and PHP version match the versions I am using. So I know I'm accessing the server. Just not sure of the Error 500 code.

I have tried accessing my projects from these URLs:

- http://192.168.1.21
- http://192.168.1.21:80
- http://laravel.dev/
- http://test.dev/
- http://localhost/

And none of them work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Require local granted` to `Require all granted`, **if not solved**, Try to edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

try access your ip computer from other device, for example your computer ip is `192.168.1.4`, if you can access this ip, then create your virtual host.

if you can not access that ip, try fixing it so ip can be accessed. then create a virtual hosts.