# Accessing localhost API from android device

Tags: flutter, api, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm developing a Flutter app on a physical android device, I don't know much about networking and I'm having a trouble using an API from the phone to a local database on my laptop.
I reviewed all the answers in this post

[Cannot connect to localhost API from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889837/cannot-connect-to-localhost-api-from-android-app)

Nothing seems to work for me, I'm using Apache server on XAMPP, and the API works just fine from the laptop (127.0.0.1:8000/api/Students) but when I try to access it from the phone it doesn't work (I replaced 127.0.0.1 with the IP of my laptop which I took from ipconfig)

[XAMPP control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeYaQ.png)

when I try to access the server from the phone using laptop-IP:80 it access normally the same with laptop-IP:80/phpmyadmin
[XAMPP dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmLrB.jpg)
but only when my phone is connected to the laptop mobile hotspot, when I connect the two devices to the same WIFI network it shows that it's unreachable:

but when I try laptop-IP:8000/api/Students this happens:

[this site can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h4Wp.jpg)

I tried to modify Apache httpd.conf:

#Listen 12.34.56.78:80

```
Listen 8000      <-- Added this
```

from what I understood this makes the server listens to port 8000 but I'm left with the same problem

NOTE: all the pictures show my attempts to use the API on my phone's Chrome browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do some tweaks to the url to access it in the device as `localhost` is only known to the machine not the devices on which the app is running.

The urls are different for different devices

1. Emulator
2. Real phone (with usb debugging)

---

##### 1.Emulator

```
static const baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000";
```

##### 2.Real Device

```
static const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000";
```

- Additionally you need to run these command in your cmd,

  ```
    adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
  ```

---

Now your requests would go like:

```
 get('$baseUrl/api/Students');
```

Comment: I'm still trying to test the API on Chrome before adding it to the code, it's not working on the browser in the first place

Comment: Then the question needs to be change, question says `Accessing localhost API from android device` to which my answer is. If your api is not working try to check the backend. and provide code where you are finding the error

Comment: the API is working fine on my laptop as I mentioned, the problem is when I try to use from a remote device

Comment: by remote device do you mean emulator or real device ?

Comment: a real device, I entered the API's URL in Chrome after replacing the home address with my laptop's IP address

Comment: No dont use laptop address, try the solution , which i have provided in the post step by step, and then it will work, first you need to enable the usb debugging and then you need to run the said code in the command prompt and then you can access it as localhost even in your real device

Comment: thank you! ADB command helped for real device!

Comment: Out of all, the `adb reverse` is the one which helped me !

Comment: after reinstalling windows 10.0.2.2 is no longer working with emulator