# Getting Connection error while connecting nodejs server flutter locally

Tags: node.js, flutter, http, localhost

I'm currently using NodeJS for my backend and I'm trying to integrating the API's locally
but I'm getting 1 error which is
`ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 202.43.120.31, port = 35948, uri=http://202.43.120.31:3001/api/`

I have already tried changing URL with deferent deferent IPs. But it is showing same.
also my laptop's WIFI and my phone is connected with same network. Please guide me with this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75232191/21590733