# How can I access my Django website on my phone using a local IP and port?

Tags: django, server, localhost, firewall

I created a website with django using `asgi` protocol.
and I would like to view this website via my phone.

After opening a local server on my pc to share the site locally

[image]

I searched for my local ip and used it with the port of the server

[image]

I also created a new inbound rule in the windows fire wall advanced security which

should let me access any site with any protocol when it is on my network.

[image]

After all of that I tried connecting to the site from my phone using this url:

http://10.0.0.6:8000/home/

(I also tried it without `home, home`  is just the landing page for my site)

and the site can't be reached... Is there anything that I am doing wrong lol?

*----***-----**_----

Comment: how are you running the asgi service?

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51895153/9544403)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on a localhost callback not `10.0.0.6:8000`.

```
... development server at 127.0.0.1:8000
```

That means it can only be accessed on your own computer.

`10.0.0.6:8000` is a public IP Address btw.

To fix it you must find your own IP Address in the local network

##### Linux

```bash
sudo ifconfig <network access example: wlo1/ether>
```

and then the inet entry

##### Windows

```
ipconfig
```

and then the ipv4 address that starts with `192.`
I can't help you too much here

#### Fix

Now use the local IP Address you got in your Django config

Answer (score 0):

If you are just testing and using the `runserver` command, you probably want to run with

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to allow others on your network to connect. If you turn debug mode off, you'll have to deal with the `allowed_hosts` [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) by adding your server's ip address.

There is a paragraph about this in the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver