# Lack of access to localhost laravel project API route in android studio

Tags: android, laravel, apache, localhost

I have a `laravel` project contains an RestFull API. I want to access to this API from android studio. I use `retrofit` library.When I run server through `artisan`, can't access `localhost` `laravel` app routes to android studio.According to this question [accessing-localhost-laravel-app-routes-to-android-studio-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294513/accessing-localhost-laravel-app-routes-to-android-studio-failed), I change base url to `http://192.168.1.103:8000/halamooz/public/api/` and run the laravel app with `apache` server.For this work, I follow this guideline [Laravel practical guide for using XAMPP](https://medium.com/@factoryhr/laravel-practical-guide-for-using-xampp-8b8824937303).Of course I don't use `XAMPP` and install apache server individually. I access web route from browser but when I try to access API route from `postman` or android studio I receive `404 page not founded` error.What is my mistake? 
I put this lines in `httpd-vhosts` file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs/halamooz/public"
ServerName exampledomain.com
ServerAlias exampledomain.com
<Directory "C:/apache/htdocs/halamooz/public">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did these steps and My problem solved.

- Step 1:
  Put your `laravel` project into `C:\apache\htdocs`.
- Step 2: Run as administrator `notepad` app and open `hosts` file from `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` path and add this line to end of file.

> 127.0.0.1        exampledomain.com www.exampledomain.com

- Step 3: Open `httpd-vhosts` file from `C:\apache\conf\extra` path and add these lines to end of file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs/NameOfProject/public"
  ServerName exampledomain.com 
  ServerAlias exampledomain.com 
  <Directory "C:/apache/htdocs/NameOfProject/public">
  AllowOverride All
  Require all Granted
  ```
- Step 4:Uncomment this line from `C:\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file.

> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

- Step 5:Use this Url to access API in `postman` or android studio project.

> http://{IPv4 of your computer}:8000/{ProjectName}/public/api/{desired method}
>     For example: 
>   http://192.168.1.3:8000/halamooz/public/api/login

- Notice: Your Android device and computer must be on a same network Internet.

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf file find

```
Listen 80
```

and below that write

```
Listen 8060
```

Then goto httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8060>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs/halamooz/public"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace DocumentRoot  with your path of project. Hope this help you

Comment: whats the error when you hit localhost:8060?

first check your apache and localhost server working properly

Comment: I put your code In the httpd-vhosts.conf file and when I test localhost:8060 in the browser, It show a list of some folder but when I try in postman I receive 404 error

Comment: pass the below headers in postman and try again

Content-type: application/json;

Comment: I did , but even didn't work. I give this url in postman: `http://localhost:8060/halamooz/public/api/login`

Comment: give it: `The requested URL /api/login was not found on this server.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182627/discussion-between-amol-rokade-and-sarina).