# Android retrofit v2 insert failed error 403

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am having this problem with my insert in android with mysql and PHP. I'm looking in my logs to identify the error but then my application crashes after this log executes:

```
/LOGS: onResponse: response: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=http://192.168.254.107/retrofit/insert.php}
```

which blocks me to connect with this URL

this is my **insert.php**

```
    <?php  

include "db.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $response = array();

    $sql = "INSERT into users values(null,'$fname','$lname','$email','$user','$pass')";

    if ($con->query($sql)) {
        $response['success'] = 1;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else{
        $response['success'] = 0;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    }

    ?>
```

And this would be my android file

**Main.java**

```
    package gd.rf.cracksoftware.retrofitregister;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class main extends Activity {


    private EditText inp_fname,inp_lname,inp_email,inp_username,inp_password;
    private static final String BASEURL = "http://192.168.254.107/";
    private final String TAG = "LOGS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inp_fname = findViewById(R.id.inp_fname);
        inp_lname = findViewById(R.id.inp_lname);
        inp_email = findViewById(R.id.inp_email);
        inp_username = findViewById(R.id.inp_user);
        inp_password = findViewById(R.id.inp_pass);
    }

    public void InsertClick(View view){
        String fname = inp_fname.getText().toString().trim();
        String lname = inp_lname.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = inp_email.getText().toString().trim();
        String user = inp_username.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = inp_password.getText().toString().trim();

        Retrofit(fname,lname,email,user,pass);
    }

    private RestAPI GetInterfaceService(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASEURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RestAPI restAPI = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
        return restAPI;
    }
    private void Retrofit(final String fname, String lname, String email, final String user, String pass){

        RestAPI restAPI = this.GetInterfaceService();
        Call<user> userCall = restAPI.register(
            fname,lname,email,user,pass
        );
        userCall.enqueue(new Callback<gd.rf.cracksoftware.retrofitregister.user>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<user> call, Response<user> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: firstname: "+fname);
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: calls: "+call.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response: "+response);
                //user isSuccess = response.body();
                //String returnResponse = isSuccess.success;

                /*if(returnResponse.trim().equals("1")){

                    Toast.makeText(main.this, "Register Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(main.this, "Register Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<user> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(main.this, "Network failed to connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

my interface class **RestAPI.java**

```
package gd.rf.cracksoftware.retrofitregister;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RestAPI {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("retrofit/insert.php")
Call<user> register(
        @Field("firstname") String first_name,
        @Field("lastname") String last_name,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("user") String user,
        @Field("pass") String pass
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code doesnt have the problem but my apache is because i ran it in the localhost but suddenly when i read the documentation about the request all granted in apache suddenly it works my bad by the way thanks guys more power stackoverflow

This might fix my problem:

[How to enable local network users to access my WAMP sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites)

Answer (score 1):

From the error code's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403), we can see it is not an authentication problem, and that it's a server side error.

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to 401, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic (like an incorrect password).

So it is not a retrofit error. Try to add some logs in your php code.

Comment: i already did in the php file to POSTMAN it inserted but when i executed in the android it has the problem of response error 403

Comment: @JamesTubiano could you post the request done by retrofit? You can use Facebook's stetho library to view network calls

Comment: @JamesTubiano I have the same problem with a user using a Samsung Galaxy A53.  Did you manage to find the reason?