# open local html page from my sever in webview android

Tags: php, android, html, webview

I have wampp server installed on my laptop. I have created a php/html page in wampp. Now I need to open this page in my Android app in webview. I am providing my app correct link of the page as http://myIPaddress:port/pageAddress but still it is not working. My phone and laptop are even connected to the same internet. In WebResourceError, I am getting errors like `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. How can I  open that page in my android app webview?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try to open that from a different tab on your browser on the laptop? Use tools like Wireshark to see if the connection actually reach your laptop.

Comment: @Jaques yes, the page is accessible from other browsers. It is not accessible from other devices.

Answer (score 0):

By default WampServer s Apache is only reachable for the localhost.

For WampServer 3 and above you need to edit your httpd-vhost.conf configuration.
You can do this by left clicking your wampmanager icon in your tray -> Apache -> httpd-vhost.conf .

Then change:

```
Require local
```

To:

```
Require all granted
```

Restart the service afterwards.

Comment: Maybe try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites