# W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:http://192.168.0.102/login/register.php
```

I'm trying to send info in a database, through my android device but.. it showing this error...

```
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(100000);

            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));


            String data = URLEncoder.encode("userid","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(userid,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(user_email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);

            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();
```

Exception:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://192.168.0.102/login/register.php
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.loginapp.logintest.background$override.doInBackground(background.java:80)
at com.loginapp.logintest.background$override.access$dispatch(background.java)
at com.loginapp.logintest.background.doInBackground(background.java)
at com.loginapp.logintest.background.doInBackground(background.java:22)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may receive a `FileNotFoundException` if you get a bad response from the server (response code != `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK`).

```java
int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
} else {
    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /json_test.php
on this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.37 (Win64) PHP/7.2.14 Server at 192.168.0.102 Port 80</address>
</body></html>`

Comment: It looks like this is, in fact, your problem. Try to fix your server permissions to allow calling from your app.

Comment: sir i have tried every possible method ... its perfectly run on emulator but not in real android device... i'm using wamp server...

Comment: The problem is definitely with your web server, as seen on the error message. You should figure out the server configuration that are blocking external requests. The emulador may work because it may be on the same computer as the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing http://192.168.0.102/login/register.php in your dekstop web browser to prove that indeed it is available or this is the correct url. You can just comment out the rest of the code in your register.php file and then echo something like

```php
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

and see if it gets displayed on your browser. It might be that the url for register.php might be wrong.

**EDIT**

As requested by Ankit, I will provide a short guide of how to make Wamp online. It can help solve the '*Forbidden*' issue and I have also posted a Youtube link to help you further. My advice is that do not set a very defined IP like `192.168.{other values}`, inside your httpd.conf file as some blogs do. My guide allows any ip address, which makes it possible to allow connections without having to keep changing the .conf files.

**OPTION 1: USING THE PUT ONLINE OPTION**

```xml
1.  Using the Put Online Option
    There is a new option on the icon tray of wamp server if you left click on it, at the bottom you will see 'Put online'. You can enable it. 
    Though I use it, I am not sure if it makes Wamp online without prior changes to *httpd.conf* and *httpd-vhost.conf* since I had 
    already made these changes before I started using it. 
    What I know is that after changing those files, my Wamp is accessible online even without clicking 'put online' option.

2.  Go to '*Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Allow an App or feature through Windows Defender firewall*' 
    Click Allow another app and under Path, browse to the location of httpd.exe (in my case it is '*C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\http.exe*').
    Then select the checkboxes for 'private' and 'public' and then click ok.
3.  Restart your Wampserver and click Put online.
4.  Please note that if you have skype, then you may need to do this if you icon does not change to green:
    i.      open skype 
    ii.     then under  Tools > Connections, untick the option for "use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connection". 
    iii.    Save and then close skype
    iv.     Restart Wampserver.
5.  Open you Windows hotspot and share it with your android phone, or vice versa.
6.  Open cmd.exe and run the command '*ipconfig*'. Get your IP address 
    e.g. 192.168.{other values}, mine is usually 192.168.137.1 but it is currently showing 192.168.43.66.
7.  In your android phone, type '*http://<that ip address from cmd>*' on your Web browser. It should load the Wampserver page on the browser.
```

**OPTION 2: CHANGING 'HTTPD.CONF' AND 'HTTPD-VHOST.CONF' FILES**

```xml
Please note that there is no deletion that is done. 
For all the lines that I have placed here, you simply need to change from some old value to a new value 
e.g require local to require granted, etc, or add a line if it is missing. 

1. Open httpd.conf file (found under '*c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache{apache_version}\conf\httpd.conf*')
2. Save a copy of this original file somewhere else just in case of anything.
3. Locate the following lines and change them to be as below;

        ..........
        #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
        Listen 0.0.0.0:80
        Listen [::0]:80

        ..........  

        # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
        ServerName localhost:80

        ..........

        # Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
        # explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
        # <Directory> blocks below.
        #
        <Directory />
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ..........

        DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
        <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
            .......
            AllowOverride all
            .......
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        .........
        <Files ".ht*">
             Require all granted
        </Files>

        .........
        <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

4.  Open httpd-vhost.conf file (found under '*c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache{apache_version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf*')
5.  Save a copy of this original file somewhere else just in case of anything.
6.  Change the code to:
    (please note that if you have other extra lines inside that are not here, please DO NOT delete them. 
     Just add what is missing and change what appears needs to be changed e.g. Require local to require all granted)

    # Virtual Hosts
    #

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
        <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    #

7.  Open hosts file (path is '*C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts*') and change or add these lines to be these 
    (you have to launch notepad or any other text editor like notepad++ as administrator so that you can be allowed to change them):
    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #   127.0.0.1       localhost
    #   ::1             localhost

8.  Go to '*Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall > Allow an App or feature through Windows Defender firewall*' 
    Click Allow another app and under Path, browse to the location of httpd.exe (in my case it is '*C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\http.exe*').
    Then select the checkboxes for 'private' and 'public' and then click ok.
9.  Restart your Wampserver and everything should be okay.
10. Please note that if you have skype, then you will need to:
    i.      open skype 
    ii.     then under  Tools > Connections, untick the option for "use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connection". 
    iii.    Save and then close skype
    iv.     Restart Wampserver.

11. Open you Windows hotspot and share it with your android phone, or vice versa.
12. Open cmd.exe and run the command '*ipconfig*'. Get your IP address 
    e.g. 192.168.{other values}, mine is usually 192.168.137.1 but it is currently showing 192.168.43.66.
13. In your android phone, type 'http://<that ip address from cmd>' on your Web browser. It should load the Wampserver page on the browser.
```

I know that this is not xml code, but this format just makes it more appealing to read through. Other helpful links that can help you are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites), [this](http://www.golibrary.co/access-wamp-server-computer-or-internet/), [this(has helpful images)](http://www.moderngyaan.com/223/how-to-access-wamp-localhost-server-on-mobile-or-other-pc/) and [How to allow wamp server 3.0 access on another computer | how to solve "Forbidden" access of wamp - Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy_f6wBGnjI):

Comment: If you are using a local server like Xampp or Wamp, you can type 192.168.0.102 (or the IP displayed when you run ipconfig on cmd.exe), in your Android browser like Opera or Chrome and it should display the server page. If it does not, then it means that your server is not accessible online to outside connections. You will need to make it online and I can provide some instructions (for Wamp) on how to do so if you require.

Comment: Yes .. it was showing the same error on my phone'schrome...  Sure i can use any kind of help...

Comment: I'm using wamp server