# Cannot access the localhost on mobile device

Tags: mobile, localhost, wampserver

I still a baby in the world of programming.
I am trying to have access to my localhost on my android mobile device.
I have a Wamp server that I turned on. My device and my laptop are on the same wifi. I turned off the firewall.

192.168.X.XX is my IPv4

On my browser's mobile, I tap "http://192.168.X.XX" and it says: Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource.
What can I do?
Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005828/how-to-enable-local-network-users-to-access-my-wamp-sites

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working. I needed to add my phone IP address to the required IP.